# How to use simple-injector with multiple projects and pass to resolve the dependencies

Tags: simple-injector

I have 4 projects in my solution,
1. MyApp.UI (MVC)
2. MyApp.Core (ClassLibrary)
3. MyApp.Data (ClassLibrary with EF implementation) and
4. MyApp.Tests

In my Data project I have 4 repository implementations and all 4 repositories are implemented **IRepositoryBase** interface and their own  repository interface Example,

```
public class RepositoryA: IRepositoryBase, IRepositoryA
{
.....
}
public class RepositoryB: IRepositoryBase, IRepositoryB
{
.....
}
```

Now in my Data project I want to create **abstract Repository Factory** which returns the concrete implementations of corresponding repository interfaces and **this class used only inside MyApp.Data project**,
For example `RepositoryFactory.GetRepository<IRepositoryA>()` must returns instance of RepositoryA class or `RepositoryFactory.GetRepository<IRepositoryB>()` must returns instance of RepositoryB class

My concerns are ,

1. How I can achieve this ? I want to use RepositoryFactory to get the Repository implementations only inside MyApp.Data project.
2. Since my UI (MVC) application already doing the boot strap do i need to pass the container to MyApp.Data project or Data project need its own container registration logic?.
3. I also want to test my MyApp.Data project separately (without UI project dependency).

If possible please give an working code for this scenario.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can elaborate why you'll need an abstract factory? I would say you won't need such a factory as [described here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100)

Comment: The reason I need a Abstract Repository Factory is if any of my implementations needed more than one repository instead of mentioning all those in the constructor I can simply inject RepositoryFactory and ask for repository concrete implementation whenever needed. Thanks for sharing the link

Comment: That would really be a bad idea because in that case the factory will become a [service locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Just put all repositories needed in the constructor. If the number of repositories is too many you're probably violating [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: [Abstract factories are a code smell](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100). Instead of having all these one-to-one interface-implementation pairs of repositories, you might want to look at a [different model](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Comment: As suggested by @Ric .Net and Steven I went without Abstract Factories and used auto wiring or constructor injection to inject the dependencies.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to use AbstractFactory pattern to use in conjunction with simple-injector container class for this problem .

I still not sure whether this is a appropriate solution for this problem

1. DataRepositoryFactory implementations,

   ```
   //Abstract data repository factory
   public interface IDataRepositoryFactory
   {
       T GetDataRepository<T>() where T : IDataRepository;
   }
   public class DataRepositoryFactory : IDataRepositoryFactory
   {
       T IDataRepositoryFactory.GetDataRepository<T>()
       {
           return (T)DataBootStraper
                    .DataDIContainer
                    .GetInstance(typeof(T));
       }
   }
   ```
2. in MyApp.Data project I created static **Bootstrap class** which use to register the data layer dependencies.

   ```
   public static class DataBootStraper
   {
       public static void BootStrap(Container container)
       {
           container.Register<IRepositoryA, RepositoryA>();
           container.Register<IRepositoryB, RepositoryB>();
           container.Register<IRepositoryC, RepositoryC>();
           //Register the DataRepositoryFactory also with container
           container.Register<IDataRepositoryFactory, DataRepositoryFactory>();
       }
   }
   ```

So this can be called from my Unit test cases as well as UI bootstraper.

3. Below is the example of the usage of factory

   ```
   public class DataRepositoryFactoryTest
   {
       private readonly IDataRepositoryFactory _repositoryFactory;
       public DataRepositoryFactoryTest(IDataRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory)
       {
           _repositoryFactory = repositoryFactory;
       }
       public IEnumerable<RepoAEntities> GetEntitiesFromRepoA()
       {
           return _repositoryFactory.GetDataRepository<IRepositoryA>().GetEntities();
       }
       public IEnumerable<RepoBEntities> GetEntitiesFromRepoB()
       {
           return _repositoryFactory.GetDataRepository<IRepositoryB>().GetEntities();
       }
       public IEnumerable<RepoCEntities> GetEntitiesFromRepoC()
       {
           return _repositoryFactory.GetDataRepository<IRepositoryC>().GetEntities();
       }
   }
   ```